# Relation between Work-Energy Theorem and Collisions

Tags: energy, work, collision

I am stuck on this idea relating the Work-Energy theorem and collisions. The derivation for the Work-Energy theorem is entirely mathematical, and simply involves

Net work on a system = $$W_{net} = \int_A^B \vec{F_{net}}\cdot d\vec{r} =\ldots = \frac{m}{2}\int_A^B\left(\frac{d}{dt} v^2\right) dt = \Delta K_{sys}$$

My interpretation is that, if this is an equality, then the change in the kinetic energy must be due to the work of some external force on our system. But if we consider a collision involving two balls with no net external forces, by definition (and experimentation and the like), $\Delta K_{sys} = 0 $ for elastic collisions, $\Delta K_{sys} < 0$ for inelastic collisions, and $\Delta K_{sys} > 0$ for superelastic collisions. Textbooks online and Kleppner and Kolenkow attribute the change in/constancy of kinetic energy of the system to interaction forces during the collision and the work they do. But how are these interaction forces between balls of any relevance if they are internal to the system? How can the work of these internal forces change the system's kinetic energy if such a change can only be attributed to the work of external forces?

Similarly, even if we were to try to compute in some way the relevance of these interaction forces, how does them being conservative or non-conservative affect the velocities/kinetic energies of the balls? As far as I know, the conservativity of a force only relates to the work it does being path-independent or equivalently, that it is the gradient of some potential function, which is irrelevant to kinetic energies.

For further confusion, KK differentiates between elastic collisions having conservative interaction forces and inelastic collisions having non-conservative interaction forces, but doesn't say which for superelastic collisions. The example KK uses for superelastic collisions is the collision of two cocked mouse traps which release the energy stored in the springs. But the spring forces there should be conservative. In another example I found online, the instructor gave an example of a superelastic collision where the balls had some explosive chemical that ignited during the collision and increased the kinetic energies post-collision. I am not sure about the conservativity of the forces involved in the chemical explosion, but I would guess they are not conservative. Is there a defined category of interaction forces involved in superelastic collisions?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to conclude with a specific question

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  These are all good questions, but given our strict Q&A format here it's best to ask one question per post.  I would recommend you edit this post to focus on one question, and post the other question separately.

Comment: The work-energy theorem states that work of *all* forces equals change of kinetic energy. Not work of external forces only. External forces are relevant in momentum theorems. But for work, all forces are relevant.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks! I will limit myself to one question for future posts!

Comment: @JánLalinský External forces are relevant in momentum theorems, but the way we concluded that was by cancelling out internal forces in the system using Newton's 3rd law. Is it not also applicable here that when we consider the total work on a system, we consider all the contributions from each force on the system, but the net contribution from both members of a third law pair will be 0, from which only the external forces will be left to integrate?

Comment: @AndyRoo no, because contributions to work are terms (force) . (displacement). Forces between two particles are of same magnitude and opposite direction, but displacements of the two particles are not necessarily the same, so those two contributions to work do not necessarily cancel each other.

Comment: @JánLalinský Great point! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been indicated, you have asked multiple questions, whereas you should focus on one question per post. However, I think a major part of the problem you are having is due to the mixing of two different but related concepts:

(1) The change in kinetic energy of a *particle* or rigid *object* due to net work done on the particle or object is net work done *by all forces*, not just external forces, per the work energy theorem

(2) The change in total mechanical energy (KE + PE) of a *system*, due to net external work done on a *system*.

Although you have referred to the work energy theorem as the the net work done on a "system", you will find that the most most common statement of the theorem is the "net work done on a *particle* or *object* equals its change in kinetic energy". In my view, the use of the term "system" in connection with the work energy theorem, as is sometimes done, is problematic because a "system" can undergo a change potential energy (PE) as well as kinetic energy (KE) as a result of net work on the system, whereas an particle or object alone cannot undergo a change in PE. And that's because PE is a system property and not a property of an object alone.

> $\Delta K_{sys} < 0$ for inelastic collisions

For inelastic collisions conservation of mechanical KE does not apply. You can use the WET to analyze collisions with respect to the average impact force during a collision. An example is given here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/carcr.html#cc1

> $\Delta K_{sys} > 0$ for superelastic collisions

Here the increase in KE has to do with conservation of mechanical energy of an isolated system (concept 2 above), which can be stated as, in the absence of external work,

$$\Delta KE+\Delta PE=0$$

So for the "superelastic" collision, the increase in KE simply equals the decrease in PE stored in the system (elastic potential energy in the case of the example of sprung mousetraps, or stored chemical potential energy in the case of explosives, though chemical potential energy is not "mechanical" energy)

> How can the work of these internal forces change the system's kinetic
> energy if such a change can only be attributed to the work of external
> forces?

Because the change in the KE of a ***system*** is not only attributable to external forces. The change in KE plus the change in PE of a system is.  Internal forces can convert KE to PE or PE to KE such that for the system $\Delta KE+\Delta PE=0$.

> As far as I know, the conservativity of a force only relates to the
> work it does being path-independent or equivalently, that it is the
> gradient of some potential function, which is irrelevant to kinetic
> energies.

Conservative forces are not irrelevant to kinetic energies. A change in PE equals the negative of the work done by a conservative force. For an isolated system, not subjected to dissipative forces, an increase/decrease in PE must be accompanied by a decrease/increase in KE of an equal amount.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Understood! I'll limit myself to one/a narrower breadth of questions for future posts. In response to 1), isn't it true that we do consider all forces that are acting on the particle, but the internal forces of the particle cancel out due to Newton's third law? When we calculate the total work on the particle, and we can sum up the individual contribution from each force, but the sum of the work done by both members of a third law pair will be 0, hence only the work due to external forces remains.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I like your distinction between WET for a system vs. for a particle. That idea, along with the distinction between K of a system vs sum of individual K's in a system has clarified some of my confusion (I didn't even define K of a system). Regarding your last point though, for an isolated collision, if $K_{sys}$ changes along with a commensurate change in $P_{sys}$, how do you explain the work done by non-conservative interaction forces that does change $K_{sys}$ without a change in $P_{sys}$? Wouldn't the dissipative forces forces be internal to the system?

Comment: @AndyRoo Conservation of mechanical energy for an isolated system only applies when there are no internal dissipative forces, such as kinetic friction. Think about a bob-pendulum-earth system. As the bob moves back and forth KE is converted to PE and vice versa for conservation of mechanical energy, i.e., $\Delta KE+\Delta PE =0$. But if there are dissipative forces such as air resistance, friction at the swivel, etc., then the pendulum eventually comes to a stop and mechanical energy is not conserved.

Comment: Regarding internal forces of a particle (or object) they only involve $\Delta PE$ at the intermolecular level where changes in molecular separation are possible. But WET applies to rigid (non deformable) particles and objects which, by definition, cannot undergo changes in molecular separation. In addition, WET applies to mechanical KE and PE. That is KE and PE at the macroscopic level not the  microscopic level, the latter of which is not mechanical energy but internal energy (PE and KE at the molecular level).

Comment: I'll spend some time trying to rewrite what you are saying mathematically. Also, I did not know that WET only applies to rigid bodies, so that is news to me, but I'll look into that and those ideas on internal energy at the molecular level. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AndyRoo OK, no problem. Please let know what you learn. Good luck!

Comment: @AndyRoo Regarding WET and deformable  bodies, I misspoke.  It does apply and can be used to calculate average impact forces during collisions involving deformation. It is conservation of mechanical energy that does not apply to a body that permanently deforms. Sorry about that. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First word of caution, you need to be careful about which kinetic energy you are talking about. The theorem you quoted can be applied to a point, but when you apply it to a system, the $\vec v$ is the speed of the center of mass and $m$ the total mass, so your $K_{sys}$ is not the sum of the kinetic energies of individual particles, which I will write $K_{tot}$, but rather the kinetic energy of the overall translation movement, so you should rather write it $K_G$. Actually, due to Huygen's theorem, $K_{tot} \geq K_G$ with the difference being the kinetic energy of the system in the frame moving at speed $\vec v_G$ compared to your reference frame.

If you're interested in $K_G$, your concern still stands. As you pointed out, the fact that the interaction forces are conservative is not necessary for $K_G$ to remain constant. The relevant condition is Newton's 3rd law, that is every force is matched with an equal and opposite force. Since this is the case for conservative forces, the conservative criterion makes it a sufficient condition for total kinetic energy conservation (but, I will reiterate, not necessary).

For example, the usual example of interaction forces violating Newton's 3rd law would be the full electromagnetic one (including relativistic corrections). In this case, the system will lose some $K_G$, and it turns out that it goes to the EM field.

However, if you're interested in $K_{tot}$, the conservative nature of the interaction is extremely relevant as $K_{tot}$ can vary even if Newton's 3rd law holds. This should resolve your confusion surrounding the classification of elastic, non-elastic and super-elastic collisions. In particular, the final examples of super-elastic show that you have an increase of $K_{tot}$, but constant $K_G$.

Finally, a final note on the conservative nature of forces. Conservation of energy is always true, so every force you'll meet in nature is conservative. However, if your model does not incorporate the full picture, they can appear to be non-conservative. For example, the drag force in fluid mechanics is non-conservative when only considering the object moving through the fluid but becomes conservative if you take into account the full energy of the fluid (and its internal energy if it is viscous). This is why in your final example of superelastic collisions, while the underlying forces are conservative, from your interacting particles perspective they are non-conservative.

Hope this helps and tell me if you need more clarification.

Comment: That makes sense, I see now that there is indeed a difference between the sum of the kinetic energies of the individual particles vs. the kinetic energy of the system/CoM since the sum of squares does not equal the square of sums. I'm not sure what you mean when you say "this is the case for conservative forces" (having a third law pair). I'm not sure how conservativity of a force implies having a 3rd law pair.

Comment: Similarly, I'm not sure what you mean when you related the conservation of energy to conservative forces. Friction is a "natural" non-conservative force but it still satisfies the conservation of energy, just not mechanical energy. This is however accounted for in the work done by non-conservative forces, and thus by the Work-Energy theorem.

Comment: For your first comment, it comes from the definition: let $r_1,r_2$ the positions of the two points on which is applied respectively due to interactions $F_1,F_2$. Saying the forces are conservative means that there is a function $U(r)$ such that $F_1=\nabla_1 U(r_1-r_2)$ and $F_2=\nabla_2 U(r_1-r_2)$, so $F_1=-F_2$.

Comment: For your second comment, I was addressing your concern that non-conservative forces in superelastic collisions arose from conservative ones like in the case of the spring or the chemical reaction. I tried to explain that whether a force was conservative was purely due to how much information you include in your model, and that at a fundamental level, all forces are conservative. Your question was not clearly posed at the end so I just guessed where you might have been confused.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on how certain forces may appear non-conservative. I had to do some extra reading to understand what you meant. A quick search from another StackOverflow problem points out counterexamples of forces that are conservative but do not satisfy Newton's 3rd law, is there something I am missing? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/464323/do-conservative-forces-obey-newtons-laws-of-motion.

Comment: The reason why my above proof doesn’t apply to these cases is that you extend the notion of conservative in this case. Typically for electromagnetism (which I had mentioned), you don’t only have a potential $U$ but also a vector potential as well. In general, people will say that a force is conservative if it derives from a Lagrangian. So yeah in this case you don’t have Newton’s third law, or more generally conservation of momentum, unless if you take into account the force mediating field.

Comment: Those topics are currently beyond my understanding at the moment, but I hope to get there some day and the details sound fascinating. Thanks for the help!